# Win10 removed apps leave broken start tiles

Tags: deployment, windows-10, sccm

I'm deploying an unaltered Win10, Enterprise 1709 WIM via SCCM Task Sequence that is configured to deprovision apps using [Michael Niehaus's method](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2015/11/11/removing-windows-10-in-box-apps-during-a-task-sequence/) and it turns off the installation of consumer apps via the registry setting:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent" /v ^
  DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

as is discussed in many places including [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2015/11/23/seeing-extra-apps-turn-them-off/)

In the end, the apps are all removed (or never installed), but the start menu is still showing "broken" tiles for them:

[image: Start menu with "P~microsoft..."]

I have not attempted to customize the Start Menu in any way.  I just want it to be mostly empty as it is supposed to be when applying these settings.

Why might this be happening and how might I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: The "erroneous", "defaultuser0" account/profile is necessary - don't delete it!

---

I figured out the problem and thought somebody might find it helpful in the future... the "defaultuser0" account is needed!

On other systems (and a different imaging process entirely -- Ghost), I have noticed a defaultuser0 account (in the Admin group!) and profile when I was logged in and installing custom software.  As is described in [many](https://superuser.com/questions/1152792/what-is-defaultuser0-and-is-it-safe-to-delete) [other](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security-winpc/defaultuser0-created-on-clean-install-of/e2333e94-ef5f-4932-8754-fd4ce27ae33b) [places](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d953f2bb-d6b6-45e5-a435-d44e260dbec8/windows-10-creator-update-defaultuser0-user-profile?forum=win10itprosetup), this account is some kind of bug/error and it should be (and has been) safely delete-able.  I've never seen any issues with deleting it.

Apparently, in some situations, deleting it does cause a problem.

Because that defaultuser0 account is apparently reasonably prevalent, one of the last steps in my process ("Task Sequence") that installs a default Windows 10 1709 Enterprise and some software and configures default settings was to delete the "defaultuser0" account and profile if they exist.  As soon as I commented out the lines:

```
net user defaultuser0 /DELETE
Del /F /S /Q %SystemDrive%\Users\defaultuser0
```

of the completion script that runs just before the final reboot, all the Start menu items went away and I got a start menu with only the Edge, OneNote and Photos tiles as I had expected all along.  In addition to fixing the Start Menu, a few other unusual behaviors (e.g. first user to log in must do so twice) that I was going to track down later went away.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening, but I would guess it's just a bug where with the id based method for start menu layouts there is no proper check to see if the app is still present.

To fix it I would suggest using the start menu customization you are currently not using.

Create a start menu template by manually creating the layout you want and then either exporting it with the powershell commandlet:

```
Export-StartLayout
```

Details about the usage of the commandlet as well as manual creation and customization of the layout xml can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/start-layout-xml-desktop).

Save the file as LayoutModification.xml

Add a task sequence step to copy the file to C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell

e.g. a commandline step:

```
cmd /c "copy ^"<path (works even with spaces) to xml file>^" C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell /Y"
```

if you have some directly accessable share or a disitrbution point based cmd file that copies the xml. This would set up a template for the start menu that users can still modify afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I found the solution, but you showing that the start-menu could be customized without needing to run `Import-StartLayout` (by just copying the .xml) was useful later.